# Do Loop Difficulty

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop this program but only if the state name entered doesn't match any of the tabs (labeled by states)

```vb
    'searches worksheets for state value
    For Each c In Worksheets
    Do
        'asks user for a state name
        sName = InputBox("Enter a state:")
            If sName = c.Name Then
                Exit Sub
        End If
    Next c
    
    'insert state on Allstates page
    wsAllStates.Select 'start on AllStates page
    Range("A1").Select 'starting point on cell
            
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select 'find the name of the bottom state
    ActiveCell.Value = sName 'write in the name of the state

    'add the new sheet
    Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)      'create a new sheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = sName            'and name it

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    'asks user for information
        sHead = InputBox("Enter the state's headquarters:")
        Branches = InputBox("Enter the amount of brand offices:")
        s2019 = InputBox("Enter the amount of sales in 2022:")

        'places information in appropriate cells with identifiers
        .Offset(0, 0).Value = "Headquarters" 'set value
        .Offset(0, 1) = sHead
        .Offset(1, 0).Value = "Branch offices" 'set value
        .Offset(1, 1) = Branches
        .Offset(2, 0).Value = "Sales in 2022" 'set value
        .Offset(2, 1) = s2019
    End With

'return to Allstates page
wsAllStates.Activate
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: You have the `Do` but you don't have the closing `Loop` statement.

Comment: `sName = InputBox("Enter a state:")` should be the first line, outside of the loop (and remove the `Do`)

Comment: I want it to ask for a new input if the entered value is already on the sheet

Answer (score 1):

### Nested `Do` and `For...Each...Next` Loops

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub DoForEachNextLoopSimple()
    
    Dim ssh As Object
    Dim sName As String
    Dim SheetFound As Boolean
    
    Do
        sName = InputBox("Enter a state:")
        If Len(sName) = 0 Then Exit Sub
        
        SheetFound = False
        For Each ssh In Sheets
            If StrComp(ssh.Name, sName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                SheetFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next ssh
        
    Loop Until SheetFound = False

End Sub


Sub DoForEachNextLoopEDU()
    
    Dim ssh As Object
    Dim sName As String
    Dim SheetFound As Boolean
    
    Do
        sName = InputBox("Enter a state:")
        If Len(sName) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Canceled or no entry."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        SheetFound = False
        For Each ssh In Sheets
            If StrComp(ssh.Name, sName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                SheetFound = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next ssh
        
        If SheetFound Then
            MsgBox "The sheet name '" & ssh.Name & "' is already taken.", _
                vbCritical
        End If
        
    Loop Until SheetFound = False

    MsgBox "Will use '" & sName & "' as the worksheet name.", vbInformation

End Sub


Sub FullMyWay()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ssh As Object
    Dim sName As String
    
    Do
        sName = InputBox("Enter a state:")
        If Len(sName) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Canceled or no entry.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        On Error Resume Next
            Set ssh = wb.Sheets(sName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ssh Is Nothing Then
            Exit Do
        Else
            MsgBox "The sheet name '" & ssh.Name & "' is already taken.", _
                vbCritical
        End If
    Loop
        
    Dim ErrNum As Long
    On Error Resume Next
        wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)).Name = sName
        ErrNum = Err.Number
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ErrNum <> 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        wsAllStates.Select
        MsgBox "'" & sName & "' is an invalid sheet name.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = Application.Transpose( _
        Array("Headquarters", "Branch Offices", "Sales in 2022"))
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To 3, 1 To 2)
    
    Data(1, 2) = InputBox("Enter the state's headquarters:")
    Data(2, 2) = InputBox("Enter the amount of brand offices:")
    Data(3, 2) = InputBox("Enter the amount of sales in 2022:")
        
    With wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count).Range("A1").Resize(3, 2)
        .Value = Data
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With

    With wsAllStates ' new name to 'AllStates'
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sName
        .Select
        .Range("A1").Select
    End With
        
    'wb.Save
        
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a bit too advanced. I need it to run as one program

Comment: The first two procedures show you how to meet your requirement i.e. a `Do` loop, that doesn't allow the program to continue unless the sheet name is not taken, and a `For...Each...Next` loop to loop through the sheets. You need to use it at the beginning of your code. The third procedure is all-in-one in the way that I would do it. In a nutshell, all three procedures are independent.

Comment: thank you but its a bit advanced. is there a way that I can do it without the booleans? maybe <>

Comment: @ArielleSaunders - I'd suggest you play with some of this code and get familiar with how it works. It looks good to me. You're better off upskilling yourself than "downskilling" the code.

Comment: I tried for about 15min to do it without the booleans, but it's a no-go. You only have `Exit For` and `Exit Do` at your disposal. The `Do` loop has to be the outer loop. So when a sheet is found you can only use `Exit For`, but it's the same exit as when no sheet was found and therefore the only place to have an `Exit Do`.

Comment: `if SheetFound = true`? Really? This is better written as just `if SheetFound` (or `if not SheetFound` for the opposite sense).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim sName, ws As Worksheet, wsAllStates As Worksheet
    Dim sHead, Branches, s2019
    
    '...
    '...
    Do
        sName = InputBox("Enter a state:")
        If Len(sName) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'stop asking if blank
    
        Set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no matching sheet
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName)
        On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    Loop While Not ws Is Nothing
    
    If ws Is Nothing Then  'if no existing sheet with that name
    
        'insert state on Allstates page
        'wsAllStates.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = sName
        wsAllStates.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = sName 'safer
    
        With ThisWorkbook 'add the new sheet and assign to `ws`
            Set ws = .Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)) 'create a new sheet
        End With
        ws.Name = sName 'and name it
    
        With ws.Range("A1")
            'asks user for information
            sHead = InputBox("Enter the state's headquarters:")
            Branches = InputBox("Enter the amount of brand offices:")
            s2019 = InputBox("Enter the amount of sales in 2022:")
            'places information in appropriate cells with identifiers
            .Offset(0, 0).Value = "Headquarters" 'set value
            .Offset(0, 1) = sHead
            .Offset(1, 0).Value = "Branch offices" 'set value
            .Offset(1, 1) = Branches
            .Offset(2, 0).Value = "Sales in 2022" 'set value
            .Offset(2, 1) = s2019
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet '" & sName & "' already exists"
    End If 'new sheet

    'return to Allstates page
    wsAllStates.Activate
    wsAllStates.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I have to use a do loop or for each statement